# Trying to use some of my Managed Package apex code in a test class in an Extension Package

Tags: unit-test, managed-package, managed-extension

I have an Apex class in my Managed package that contains the standard methods that do most of the work in our application.

Here is a little snipped of the managed package code...

```
public with sharing class OrderService
{
public class OrderInfo
{
     public Id OrderID;
     public Date returnDate;
     public boolean Validated;
     public string ValidationMessage;                  
}
public static void ValidateCommitOrders(List<OrderInfo> OrderInfos)
{
    a bunch of code here
}
}
```

Now I am working in an Extension Org for a customer of that package and trying to write a test class that attempts to do one of those standard processes.

Here is a snippet of that test class code...

```
   OrderService.OrderInfo OrderInfo = new OrderService.OrderInfo();
   OrderInfo.OrderId = objOR1.Id;
   List<OrderService.OrderInfo> OrderInfos = new List<OrderService.OrderInfo>{OrderInfo};
   OrderService.ValidateCommitOrders(OrderInfos);
   System.assertequals(OrderInfo.Validated,FALSE);
```

And I am getting a compile error.

```
   Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: OrderService.OrderInfo at line 1,058 column 49
```

(line 1058 is the top line in the test code sample)

Is there a way to using Managed Package apex classes in an org where the package is installed?

Any assistance/direction y'all could provide would be greatly appreciated
Angie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you are missing:

**1: Global Methods**

Your method needs to be declared as [global](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm) so that it can be accessed from outside of the managed package. **NB:** Once a method has been marked as global and the package has been uploaded, you will not be able to remove that method or change its signature

**2: Namespaces**

You need to add the [namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_namespace_prefix.htm) of your managed package to reference components from it. e.g. `abc.OrderService`

Comment: As an additional clarification, you can check the namespace prefix for your managed packages here: **Setup** -> **Installed Packages** -> _Your Package Name_ -> **Namespace Prefix** field.